# Excel VBA: How to find first empty row within a Table for a Loop routine?

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I reformatted a range of `Sheets("Records")` in a workbook as a `Table (named "RecordsTable")` to make it easier to do `INDEX(MATCH,MATCH)` functions for generating reports.... but now I screwed up my looping routine for filling that range from the input on `Sheets("FORM")`.

It used to be:

```
Set r = Sheets("Records").Range(A & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)

i = 0

   For Each c In Range("dataRange")              
   'dataRange is a list of cells to reference from the FORM input sheet

   r.Offset(0, i).Value = Worksheets("FORM").Range(c)
   i = i + 1
Next
```

However this code is now selecting the first row at the END of `"RecordsTable"` (row 501, as I defined 500 rows in my table) and inserting the data there.

I tried to change it to this:

```
Set r = Sheets("Records").ListObjects("RecordsTable").DataBodyRange("A" & Rows.Count).End(x1Up).Offset(1, 0)

i = 0

   For Each c In Range("dataRange")              

   r.Offset(0, i).Value = Worksheets("FORM").Range(c)
   i = i + 1
Next
```

But this code is still selecting row 501 and making that row part of `"RecordsTable"`.
How can I properly `Set "r" to =` the first empty row in `"RecordsTable"`?

For reference, `Column "A" in "RecordsTable"` has the header `[INV #]`. Also, when I step into the `"Set r = ..."` line, `Rows.Count` is returning a value of 1million+ (ie, total rows on the sheet) - if I understand this correctly, I want it to return a value of 500 (ie, total rows in table) - is that correct?

**EDIT**

`"dataRange"` is a single column list of cell references (I do have them labeled in column B, as @chrisneilsen suggest:

**A**

J6

Y6

J8

J10

Y8

etc.

They are the cells on `Sheets("FORM")` that I need to pull data from and populate into my table, in the order indicated in `"dataRange"`.

Comment: Real quick suggestion: See how you put the worksheet before you used `ListObjects`? Do that every time you use `Range()`, `Cells()`, `Rows.Count`, etc. That will tell VBA which sheet to get that info from. Otherwise, it's using the `ActiveSheet`, and that may produce unexpected results.

Comment: @BruceWayne  ^^ Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you really have a Table, adding data to a Table (ListObject) using it's properties and methods:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim c As Range

    Set lo = Worksheets("Records").ListObjects("RecordsTable")

    For Each c In Sheets("V").Range("dataRange")
        If Not lo.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
            lo.InsertRowRange.Cells(1, 1) = Sheets("FORM").Range(c)
        Else
            lo.ListRows.Add.Range.Cells(1, 1) = Sheets("FORM").Range(c)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Note: looping a range on sheet `V` and using that as a pointer to data on sheet `FORM`, copied from your answer - I'm assuming you know what you are doing here

Based on OP comment, adding data a single new row

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim lo As ListObject
    Dim c As Range, TableRange As Range
    Dim i As Long

    Set lo = Worksheetsheets("Records").ListObjects("RecordsTable")

    If Not lo.InsertRowRange Is Nothing Then
        Set TableRange = lo.InsertRowRange
    Else
        Set TableRange = lo.ListRows.Add.Range
    End If
    i = 1
    For Each c In Sheets("V").Range("dataRange")
        TableRange.Cells(1, i) = Sheets("FORM").Range(c)
        i = i + 1
    Next
End Sub
```

Note, this assumes that the order of the table columns is the same as the order of `dataRange`.  It may be better to include table field names in `dataRange` to avoid any mismatch issues

As mentioned in updated OP, if column labels are in the next column, replace the `For` loop with this (and add `Dim r as Range, col as long` to declarations)

```
    For Each c In Sheets("V").Range("dataRange")
        If Not c = vbNullString Then
            Set r = Worksheets("FORM").Range(c.Value)
            col = lo.ListColumns(c.Offset(, 1).Value).Index
            TableRange.Cells(1, col) = r.Value
        End If
    Next
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried using this and it is properly adding a row to the table and starting data input in the first column, but subsequent iterations continue to add the data in the first column, next available row. I have 40 cells defined in `dataRange` and I need each one to go into the next column after the one before it.

Comment: OK, that's new information.  So you want to only add one new row, and insert all data into that row?  See update

Comment: Thanks, Chris. I was trying to work that out ever since you posted and this update helps. It is still throwing me an "Application-defined or object-defined error" at `TableRange.Cells(1, i) = Sheets("FORM").Range(c)` though.

Comment: Based on your code `= Sheets("FORM").Range(c)` I'm guessing `dataRange` is a list of addresses on sheet `FROM`.  Is that correct?  If the value of `c` is not a valid address (eg `C10') that will cause an error.  can you post (edit your Q) some sample data for both `recordsTable` and `dataRange`

Comment: Q updated, as requested. Hopefully it's what you were looking for.

Comment: Looks like what I expected.  Possible cause of the error: maybe there is an issue in `dataRange`, I assume it's a Named Range - maybe its extending beyond the data so `c` is getting a blank? What's the value of `c` when you get the error?

Comment: When I mouse over `TableRange.Cells(1, i)` it shows that section as throwing the error. The value of `c` is showing as `J6`. I just checked to verify that `"dataRange"` is a defined range that only includes the 40 cells defining where on `"FORM"` I need to get data from.

Comment: I did not copy paste so I did not have the typo in my code. Mine says `Set lo = Worksheets(("Records").ListObjects("RecordsTable")`. I don't think that was the problem.

Comment: Ok, just realised `i` should be initialised to `1` (dumb error on my part, sorry, post updated)

Comment: I got it, Chris. Iterations in a range are "1" based, not "0" based. I needed to start `i = 1` not `i = 0`. It works perfectly now. Thank you so much, Chris - I really appreciate your putting up with my lack of knowledge in this.

Comment: No problem, glad to help.  See latest update to make use of column labels in `dataRange`